# Порядок байтов в числе

Tags: c++, указатели

Процессор называется Big Endian, если целые числа, занимающие несколько байтов, хранятся по следующему
правилу: младший байт записан по наибольшему адресу, и Little Endian, если младший байт хранится по наименьшему
адресу; если же порядок записи байтов в составе целого числа не совпадает ни с одним из упомянутых, назовем это
Mixed Endian. Определить тип процессора, на котором мы работаем.

Моё неверное решение:

```
int a = 0xA1B2C3D4; // любое 4-байтное число
char *p = (char*)&a;
if (p < p + 1 && p + 1 < p + 2 && p + 2 < p + 3)
    cout << "Big Endian\n";
else if (p > p + 1 && p + 1 > p + 2 && p + 2 > p + 3)
    cout << "little-endian\n";
else
    cout << "Mixed Endian\n";
```

Печатает Big Endian, хотя на сомом деле должно быть little (проверял по правильному коду из вики)
Почему так?

Comment: А как на основе этого условия ``(p < p + 1 && p + 1 < p + 2 && p + 2 < p + 3)`` можно определить где хранится младший/старший байт?

Comment: Забыли разыменовать указатели? `*p < *(p + 1)` и так далее. Закрываем как опечатку?

Comment: @Эникейщик Если я правильно понимаю, то то на что указывает p самый старший байт, а куда указывает p+3 - самый младший байт

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Не будет ли ``*p < *(p + 1)`` всегда true, независимо от способа хранения? Все-таки ``p`` всегда меньше, чем ``p+1``.

Comment: @Эникейщик: ??? Какое "p всегда меньше, чем p+1" имеет отношение к значению выражения `*p < *(p + 1)`???

Comment: @Эникейщик С точностью до наоборот. Это `p < p + 1` всегда истинно (не считая UB).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну я и говорю, что true.

Comment: @Эникейщик Тут два разных выражения. `p < p + 1` всегда `true`, а вот `*p < *(p + 1)` - зависит от того, куда показывает `p`.

Comment: @Эникейщик: Вы сначала определитесь, про какое выражение вы говорите: `p < p + 1` или `*p < *(p + 1)`. Вы вообще замечаете разницу?

Comment: @AnT Прошу простить. Я с указателями в последний раз имел дела лет 15 назад, многое подзабылось.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну так ведь и ``*p < *(p + 1)`` нельзя для данной цели использовать. Результаты для, скажем 0x2211 и 0x1122, будут разные при любом способе хранения. Так ведь?

Comment: @Эникейщик: При чем здесь "результаты для 0x2211 и 0x1122 будут разные"? Весь смысл данного подхода - взять одно конкретное значение - скажем, `0x2211`- и анализировать результаты именно для него.

Comment: @AnT Так если делать только для одного конкретного значения, то и городить ничего не надо. Достаточно сравнить содержание первой ячейки с первым/последним байтом числа. Только непонятно, зачем нужна функция, которая работает только для одного конкретного числа.

Comment: @Эникейщик: Не понимаю замечания про "для одного конкретного числа". Вам известны архитектуры, которые для разных чисел используют разный порядок байтов? По-моему достаточно проверить одно число - и все становится понятно.

Comment: @AnT Да, согласен.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибок у вас я вижу две: главная в том, что вы сравниваете указатели, а не байты, на которые они указывают. Вторая ошибка а строке

```
char *p = (char*)&a;
```

Тип `char` является знаковым, и поэтому сравнения будут происходить неправильно, так как все байты у вас отрицательные.

А вообще зачем вам такие развесистые условия? Это же можно сделать гораздо проще:

```
int a = 0xA1B2C3D4; // любое 4-байтное число
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&a;

if (*p == 0xA1)
    cout << "Big Endian\n";
else if (*p == 0xD4)
    cout << "little-endian\n";
else
    cout << "Mixed Endian\n";
```

Comment: Тип `char` **может** являться знаковым, а не "является знаковым".

Comment: @AnT, если я не ошибаюсь, в большинстве реализаций он как раз знаковый.

Comment: Во-первых,  "в большинстве реализаций" и "является знаковым" - не одно и то же. Во-вторых, в большинстве реализаций вам просто предоставляется настройка, позволяющая выбирать из двух вариантов.

Comment: @AnT, верно, но у нас тут не теоретическое обсуждение, а конкретная программа. Здесь эти нюансы совершенно неважны. Важно то, что мы не можем полагаться на то что `char`, возможно, окажется беззнаковым, а должны явно это задавать.

Comment: @freim **Тип char является знаковым, и поэтому при сравнениях будет происходить расширение знака**    У кого будет происходить расширение? И куда знак будет расширяться? В соседний байт?

Comment: @zhukov, а вот вы возьмите и проверьте. Уберите `unsigned` и запустите. Если в вашем компиляторе `char` знаковый, то вас ждет сюрприз. Впрочем вы правы - сравнение будет происходить неверно, но не из-за расширения знака. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @freim смутно понимаю о чём вы пишете. Где про эту байтовую арифметику можно почитать? Пару ссылок можно?

Comment: @zhukov, там по сути все очень просто - байт 0xA1 со знаком сравнивается с байтом 0xA1 без знака. При сравнении операнды расширяются до целого, так что сравнивается 0xFFFFFFA1 с 0x000000A1 (это если без `unsigned` конечно).

Comment: @zhukov, чтобы понять откуда появляются все эти FFFFF..., вам надо разобраться что такое дополнительный код. В русской вике все это изложено очень косноязычно, вот [тут](https://prog-cpp.ru/direct-return-additional-code/) вроде получше.

Comment: @freim  ** байт 0xA1 со знаком сравнивается с байтом 0xA1 без знака. При сравнении операнды расширяются до целого** А зачем они расширяются? Почему не сравнивается байт с байтом?

Comment: @zhukov, 0xA1 с которым идет сравнение, это не байт, а литерал, который представляет собой целое без знака. Соответственно `*p` тоже расширяется до целого, чтобы сравнивать числа одного размера. Если же вместо просто `0xA1`  в операторе 'if` написать `(char)0xA1`, то тогда расширение до целого все равно будет (во всяком случае, в VC++) но оба операнда будут одинакового типа, и сравнение отработает правильно.  "_зачем они расширяются?_" вот честно скажу - не знаю. Язык так устроен, а из каких соображений разработчики решили расширять до целого, загадка. Да, можно бы и байт с байтом сравнивать.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{


int a = 0x41424344; // любое 4-байтное число
char *p = (char*)&a;

std::cout << p[0];
std::cout << p[1];
std::cout << p[2];
std::cout << p[3];
std::cout << "\n";

if (p[0] < p[1] && p[1] < p[2] && p[2] < p[3])
    std::cout << "Big Endian\n";
else if (p[0] > p[1] && p[1] > p[2] && p[2] > p[3])
    std::cout << "little-endian\n";
else
    std::cout << "Mixed Endian\n";
}
```